# Node JS Как прочитать string в бинарном файле

Tags: node.js

Здравствуйте. Так как я не силен в node.js, прошу помощи.

Есть бинарный файл, который нужно прочитать. Столкнулся я с тем, что не знаю как читать string. Можете помочь мне с этим вопросом?

Вот мой пример:

```
var fs = require("fs");


fs.readFile('file.data', '', function(err, data) {
if (err) throw err;
var p = 0;
console.log(data.readInt16LE(p));p+=2;
console.log(data.readInt16LE(p));p+=2;
console.log(data.readInt32LE(p));p+=4;
var len = data.readInt32LE(p);p+=4;
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++ ){
    data.readInt32LE(p); p+=4;
    data.readString(64, p); p+=64; //Вот тут мне нужно прочитать string длинной 64
    data.readInt32LE(p); p+=4;
    data.readInt32LE(p); p+=4;
    data.readInt32LE(p); p+=4;
}
console.log(data.readInt32LE(p));p+=4;

console.log(data);
console.log(p);

});
```

Comment: А если просто сделать - data.readString(64, p).toString();

Comment: TypeError: data.readString is not a function Я уже все перепробовал. Думал может может библиотека какая есть , что бы так читать. Не смог ничего найти.

Comment: а если прочитать его так  buf.readDoubleLE(p).toString();  Я не монстр теории буферов, была бы на руках дата прочитал бы, а так мне сложно дать сразу правильный ответ.